# Update on any properties with odata

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

Do you know how I could update an entity in WCF Data Services with OData syntax without the key property of the entity.

For example, an entity:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to make this request:

```
PUT myservice.svc/Product('REFXX')
```

with 'REFXXX' corresponding do the Reference property (which is unique).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a IDispatchMessageInspector, parse the url and replace the match element in the request parameter with a correct syntax and the real key. I know that the key is not the real "Key" with a specific user agent or with the syntax Service.svc/Entity(SecondaryKey=value), which is used normally for multiple pk's.

so in the method AfterReceiveRequest the process is:

- parse the url Service.svc/Entity(SecondaryKey=value)
- get the key value of the entity (by building a dynamic linq expression)
- change the match element of the request with Service.svc/Entity(PKValue)

  ```
         public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
  {

      if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("UriTemplateMatchResults") && HttpContext.Current != null)
      {
          //get match for current request
          UriTemplateMatch match = (UriTemplateMatch)request.Properties["UriTemplateMatchResults"];

          Utils.ODataBasicUriParser uriParser = new Utils.ODataBasicUriParser(match.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);

          //verify if this is a SecondaryKey request
          if (uriParser.IsEntityQuery && uriParser.IsSecondaryKeyQuery)
          {               
              //TODO this syntax is also used for entities with multiple pk's, test it

              //get a new data context
              //TODO see if this can be improved, avoid two datacontext for one request 
              DataContext ctx = new DataContext();

              Type outType;
              //get entity type name from the service name 
              string entityName = DataContext.GetEntityNameByServiceName(uriParser.EntityServiceName);

              //get the pk for the entity
              string id = ctx.GetEntityId(entityName, uriParser.EntityKey, uriParser.EntityId, out outType);

              //verify if the pk has been found or cancel this to continue with standart request process
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
              {
                  Trace.TraceWarning(string.Format("Key property not found for the the entity:{0}, with secondaryKeyName:{1} and secondaryKeyValue:{2}",
                      entityName, uriParser.EntityKey, uriParser.EntityId));

                  return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
              }

              //in odata syntax quotes are required for string values, nothing for numbers
              string quote = outType.FullName == typeof(Int32).FullName || outType.FullName == typeof(Int64).FullName ? string.Empty : "'";

              //build the new standart resource uri with the primary key
              var newUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}({2}{3}{2})", match.BaseUri.ToString(), uriParser.EntityServiceName, quote, id));

              //create a new match to replace in the current request, with the new Uri
              UriTemplateMatch newMatch = NewMatch(match, newUri); 

              //set request values
              request.Properties["UriTemplateMatchResults"] = newMatch;
              request.Headers.To = newUri;
              request.Properties.Via = newUri;
          }
      }

      return null;
  }


  UriTemplateMatch NewMatch(UriTemplateMatch match, Uri newUri)
  {
      UriTemplateMatch newMatch = new UriTemplateMatch();
      newMatch.RequestUri = newUri;
      newMatch.Data = match.Data;
      newMatch.BaseUri = match.BaseUri;

      return newMatch;
  }
  ```

works for my current needs

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do this - the issue is if you pass the following request to the server (PUT myservice.svc/Product('REFXX')), how will the server know that REFXX is the value for the unique property and not the key property.

If you really want to update the client based on the unique property, make sure the server exposes that unique property as key.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: i can't do that, each client of the api has it's own unique key (crm key, tool2 key, ...)